# How to write this pandas logic for pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame without using pandas on spark API?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm totally new to Pyspark, as Pyspark doesn't have loc feature how can we write this logic. I tried by specifying conditions but couldn't get the desirable result, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
df['Total'] = (df['level1']+df['level2']+df['level3']+df['level4'])/df['Number']
df.loc[df['level4'] > 0, 'Total'] += 4
df.loc[((df['level3'] > 0) & (df['Total'] < 1)), 'Total'] += 3
df.loc[((df['level2'] > 0) & (df['Total'] < 1)), 'Total'] += 2
df.loc[((df['level1'] > 0) & (df['Total'] < 1)), 'Total'] += 1
```

Comment: can you share what you tried in pyspark? did you try `when()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a data like the following

```
data_ls = [
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 10),
    (5, 5, 5, 5, 10)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls). \
    toDF(['level1', 'level2', 'level3', 'level4', 'number'])

# +------+------+------+------+------+
# |level1|level2|level3|level4|number|
# +------+------+------+------+------+
# |     1|     1|     1|     1|    10|
# |     5|     5|     5|     5|    10|
# +------+------+------+------+------+
```

You're actually updating `total` column in each statement, not in an if-then-else way. Your code can be replicated (as is) in pyspark using multiple `withColumn()` with `when()` like the following.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('total', (func.col('level1') + func.col('level2') + func.col('level3') + func.col('level4')) / func.col('number')). \
    withColumn('total', func.when(func.col('level4') > 0, func.col('total') + 4).otherwise(func.col('total'))). \
    withColumn('total', func.when((func.col('level3') > 0) & (func.col('total') < 1), func.col('total') + 3).otherwise(func.col('total'))). \
    withColumn('total', func.when((func.col('level2') > 0) & (func.col('total') < 1), func.col('total') + 2).otherwise(func.col('total'))). \
    withColumn('total', func.when((func.col('level1') > 0) & (func.col('total') < 1), func.col('total') + 1).otherwise(func.col('total'))). \
    show()

# +------+------+------+------+------+-----+
# |level1|level2|level3|level4|number|total|
# +------+------+------+------+------+-----+
# |     1|     1|     1|     1|    10|  4.4|
# |     5|     5|     5|     5|    10|  6.0|
# +------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

---

We can merge all the `withColumn()` with `when()` into a single `withColumn()` with multiple `when()` statements.

```
data_sdf. \
withColumn('total', (func.col('level1') + func.col('level2') + func.col('level3') + func.col('level4')) / func.col('number')). \
withColumn('total', 
           func.when(func.col('level4') > 0, func.col('total') + 4).
           when((func.col('level3') > 0) & (func.col('total') < 1), func.col('total') + 3).
           when((func.col('level2') > 0) & (func.col('total') < 1), func.col('total') + 2).
           when((func.col('level1') > 0) & (func.col('total') < 1), func.col('total') + 1).
           otherwise(func.col('total'))
           ). \
show()

# +------+------+------+------+------+-----+
# |level1|level2|level3|level4|number|total|
# +------+------+------+------+------+-----+
# |     1|     1|     1|     1|    10|  4.4|
# |     5|     5|     5|     5|    10|  6.0|
# +------+------+------+------+------+-----+
```

It's like [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [SQL's `case` statements](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp).